# How to not trigger Wildfire mystery

Tags: surviving-mars

I just have two small domes with 50 people, half of the tech tree, 500 research points each sol and I just triggered somehow wildfire mystery.

I just want to react quickly but there is no way to do some research based on Wildfire, I don't see any options in Laboratory or Medical building. Is there any way I can not trigger this mystery at all? I feel I'm not ready for it right now. This is my first playthrough.

Answer (score 2):

When you start a new game, you can choose which mystery you will get in the settings. You can choose an easier mystery, or disable mysteries entirely.

If you stay with random, it is weighted to give you mysteries you haven't seen. This means for your next game, you are very unlikely to see it.

Comment: I discovered that if you are not scanning anomaly with eye icon then it will not trigger the wildfire. If You feel you're ready for it you can start scanning and after some anonaly there will be something with crashed rocket and some mysterious box with the caption danger that your scientisc will take into warehouse. From this moment 4-5 sols and the wildfire starts from corrupted laboratory...